# Intel RAID setup blocking PC from booting

Tags: hard-drive, sata, dell

I had an external drive fail,
(described here [How to save data from an external disk that died](https://superuser.com/questions/1827273/how-to-save-data-from-an-external-disk-that-died?noredirect=1#comment2879868_1827273))

Following the advice from the comments I dismantled the case, extracted the hard drive, took off the USB/SATA adapter board and plugged the disk into the computer via SATA. I have a Dell D07S001, the space is really tight in there, I don't seem to have a choice of multiple SATA connectors on the motherboard. I had to disconnect the DVD ROM in order to connect the disk.

When I turned on the computer, I was greeted by this screen:
[image]

Which on one hand made me hopeful, because the system clearly sees the disk, so it's not completely dead. On the other hand I'm now stuck on this screen. Pressing Ctrl+I as the screen says does nothing. I googled the issue and found posts suggesting you should press Ctrl+Shift+I instead. But no amount of pressing Ctrl+I or Ctrlt+Shift+I (any combination of left and right Ctrl and Shift) ever gets me past this screen.

I switched off the computer, disconnected the disk, started it again and went into BIOS. I poked around trying to disable RAID so this screen hopefully doesn't come up. I found something called SATA settings (or something like that) which had 4 options:

- Disabled
- ATA
- EHCI
- RAID enabled

with the last option selected. I tried selecting either option 2 or 3, but with either option Windows would fail to boot and I would get some kind of repair utility.

What should I do? I don't really have the option of trying this with another computer right now. I read somewhere that SATA can be configured for "hot-swapping", i.e. I should be able to connect it while the PC is running. But I don't know how to set that up, and I'm worried I might damage the disk further. I'm already anxious about manipulating a disk with questionable health, connecting and disconnecting it over and over while trying different things.

EDIT:
I managed to open the settings by following a suggestion from the internet - I spammed Ctrl+I even before the screen above showed up.
This is what I got:
[image]

This looked promising at first, until I realized that only options 1. Create RAID Volume and 6. Exit are available. The rest are sort of "greyed out" and when I press the up and down arrows, the selection jumps between option 1. and 6.

Option 1 is something I definitely don't want, as these are not RAID disks and I don't want them to be RAID disks. Both disks have unrelated data that I need. It looks like option 3 might be what I need, although the word "reset" is scary. But like I said that's not available. When I select Exit I get a confirmation dialog, and when I confirm I get a black screen with an underscore in the top left corner blinking at me like I'm Neo about to be contacted by Trinity.

What do I do? The system even recognizes that both disks are Non-RAID, so why can't it accept it, and instead tries to force RAID on me?

Comment: Neither disk is part of an Intel RST RAID so performing a reset and making them not part of the RAID wouldn’t do much even if you could select that option

Comment: this question had a comment thread, where did it go?

Comment: You mean the comment threat that contained at least one comment with vulgarity? It was reported and deleted by a moderator.